Convert Text to Audio File using SAPI
I want to convert a given text to an audio file in a c++ console application. I am developing the application in visual studio on windows 10. I found a related code on Microsoft's learn challenge simple tts guide sapi 5.4 webpage. Below is the code that i am using.
#include <iostream>
#include <sphelper.h>


using namespace std;


int main()
{
    HRESULT             hr = S_OK;
    CComPtr <ISpVoice>      cpVoice;
    CComPtr <ISpStream>     cpStream;
    CSpStreamFormat         cAudioFmt;

    //Create a SAPI Voice
    hr = cpVoice.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SpVoice);

    //Set the audio format
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = cAudioFmt.AssignFormat(SPSF_22kHz16BitMono);
    }

    //Call SPBindToFile, a SAPI helper method,  to bind the audio stream to the file
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {

        hr = SPBindToFile(L"c:\\ttstemp.wav", SPFM_CREATE_ALWAYS,
            &cpStream; , &cAudioFmt.FormatId(), cAudioFmt.WaveFormatExPtr());
    }

    //set the output to cpStream so that the output audio data will be stored in cpStream
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = cpVoice->SetOutput(cpStream, TRUE);
    }

    //Speak the text "hello world" synchronously
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = cpVoice->Speak(L"Hello World", SPF_DEFAULT, NULL);
    }

    //close the stream
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = cpStream->Close();
    }

    //Release the stream and voice object
    cpStream.Release();
    cpVoice.Release();
}

As far as I understand this code must produce a wav file under drive c: saying "hello world".
In addition to this code I have used a sphelper.h header file. I found the raw code for sphelper.h file on github. But my solution does not work.
When I compile this code in c++ in visual studio the compiler gives error. One error is 'GetVersionExW': was declared deprecated. And the other error is 'expected an expression' for the line
hr = SPBindToFile(L"c:\\ttstemp.wav", SPFM_CREATE_ALWAYS,
            &cpStream; , &cAudioFmt.FormatId(), cAudioFmt.WaveFormatExPtr());

I guess the first error has to do with the sphelper.h header file. The problem is solved for the first error if I do something like this:
#define FKG_FORCED_USAGE 1
#include <sphelper.h>
#undef FKG_FORCED_USAGE

Or something like this:
#pragma warning(disable:4996) 
#include <sphelper.h>
#pragma warning(default: 4996)

And the problem for the second error is solved when i remove the semicolon (;) after &cpstream.
The code compiles when I remove these two errors. But even in that case the program does not produce a wav file under drive c:.

Is recommend removing the problems you've already solved from your question, they're not really relevant and will lead to people answering how to solve those problems rather than the problem you actually have

Does your program have permission to write to c:\ttstemp.wav? You should also print something out when SUCCEEDED(hr) is false so that you know where and why your program is failing

Why would you put a semi-colon after cpStream? This is the kind of error you make when you are just copying code, with no real understanding of what you are doing. It's not possible to learn C++ in this way, and only rarely is it possible to produce working code. If you want to be a C++ programmer, you need to spend some time studying C++ from first principles.

hr = SPBindToFile(L"c:\\ttstemp.wav", SPFM_CREATE_ALWAYS,
            &cpStream; , &cAudioFmt.FormatId(), cAudioFmt.WaveFormatExPtr());

There's a semicolon after &cpStream
'GetVersionExW': was declared deprecated:
My compiler doesn't complain this; also you should be able to just ignore it since it's WinAPI using it not you.
Another mistake I spotted:
Before consuming COM APIs you must call CoInitializeEx first, so add CoInitializeEx(nullptr, COINIT_MULTITHREADED); to the beginning of main.
It doesn't generate a file under C:
Writing to C requires admin privileges. If you correctly handle errors you should be able to see that SPBindToFile returns with Invalid Parameters. Change L"c:\\ttstemp.wav" to something like L"c:\\users\\<your username>\\desktop\\ttstemp.wav"

Thanks your suggestion solved the problem. First I removed the semicolon (;) after &cpstream and I added the following code:
 #define FKG_FORCED_USAGE 1
    #include <sphelper.h>
    #undef FKG_FORCED_USAGE

After this I added
CoInitializeEx(nullptr, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);

to the beginning of main. Now my solution compiles and produces a wav file.
